# how to update two columns dynamically in pandas based on single column value?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe as below. I want to add two columns winning_team and losing_team. How can I populate these columns based on home and away score condition? I want to update both winning_team and losing_team columns in one pass.

```
         date home_team away_team  home_score  away_score tournament
0  1872-11-30  Scotland   England           0           0   Friendly
1  1873-03-08   England  Scotland           4           2   Friendly
2  1874-03-07  Scotland   England           2           1   Friendly
3  1875-03-06   England  Scotland           2           2   Friendly
4  1876-03-04  Scotland   England           3           0   Friendly
5  1876-03-25  Scotland     Wales           4           0   Friendly
6  1877-03-03   England  Scotland           1           3   Friendly
7  1877-03-05     Wales  Scotland           0           2   Friendly
```

Comment: What happens in the case of ties?

Comment: I want to put N/A in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `numpy`. We'll use argsort to get the indices which can be used as inputs to the "fancy" indexing of `np.take_along_axis` to get the team names. Use `where` to `NaN` matches where there was a tie, then `concat` the result back to the DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

idx = np.argsort(df[['home_score', 'away_score']].to_numpy(), axis=1)
arr = df[['home_team', 'away_team']].to_numpy()

df1 = (pd.DataFrame(np.take_along_axis(arr, idx, axis=1),
                    columns=['loser', 'winner'],
                    index=df.index)
         .where(df.home_score != df.away_score))

df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
```

---

```
         date home_team away_team  home_score  away_score tournament     loser    winner
0  1872-11-30  Scotland   England           0           0   Friendly       NaN       NaN
1  1873-03-08   England  Scotland           4           2   Friendly  Scotland   England
2  1874-03-07  Scotland   England           2           1   Friendly   England  Scotland
3  1875-03-06   England  Scotland           2           2   Friendly       NaN       NaN
4  1876-03-04  Scotland   England           3           0   Friendly   England  Scotland
5  1876-03-25  Scotland     Wales           4           0   Friendly     Wales  Scotland
6  1877-03-03   England  Scotland           1           3   Friendly   England  Scotland
7  1877-03-05     Wales  Scotland           0           2   Friendly     Wales  Scotland
```